# Remove unwanted elements from string and only keep text

Tags: php, preg-replace

I got the following element in a string and i want to only keep "Alex"

```
<p class="f10">
  <label class="fname">First name</label>
  <input class="select" type="text" value="" name="person[firstname]">
  Alex
</p>
```

I tried with preg_replace but i cant remove the inside element of

How i can do it?

Comment: You always know what exact value you want from the string?

Comment: Yes only inside plaintext for <p>. Also label and input classes are static

Comment: There isnt a command to remove all <label> and <input> from a string?

Comment: I think you gotta use http://us1.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$daya= '<p class="f10">
        <label class="fname">First name</label>
        <input class="select" type="text" value="" name="person[firstname]">
        Alex
        </p>';

echo strip_tags(preg_replace("/<label\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/label>/s", "", $daya));
```

Output will be Alex

Comment: Ye true daya but after a lot of spaces :( i dont know why... Let me check

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$x = '<p class="f10">
<label class="fname">First name</label>
<input class="select" type="text" value="" name="person[firstname]">
Alex
</p>';

$x = strip_tags($x);

echo str_replace('First name','',$x);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This code for get best result

1. make As A string to html code 
    $x ='First name
         Alex

   ';
2. Use str_replace function

   $x = str_replace("First name", "", strip_tags($x));
3. print Result
   echo $x;